# Can I use this screen from a digital brochure with the Pi?

Tags: display, connection, screen

I recently received a kind of digital brochure that was just this large screen in a cardboard envelope. I ripped it out and I'm curious - can I drive this with a Pi? I tried looking for ribbon cable adapters but that didn't seem to turn up what I was looking for. I have a Pi 4.

[image]

Comment: To know whether this is possible will require a deep dive into any and all information you can pull off of the circuit board/chips in order to determine how you can build/locate an interface that the Pi can work with. Once you find details as to how it operates, then you can ask specific questions that people who are knowledgable about the capabilities and limitations of the Raspberry Pi can actually answer.

Comment: highly doubt you;ll be able to use a "ribbon adapter" to directly connect to a pi, bypassing the controller that came with the display

Comment: A standard answer to this kind of question is that if you had the skills and knowledge to do it, you wouldn't be asking, mostly because you'd feel it was a waste of time -- ie., not worthwhile -- which is that much more true if you *don't* know it, just it will take you longer to figure out ;)   WRT the ribbon cable, pretty sure that's just a sort of form factor.   There's no standard protocol in use like USB, etc., so you'd have to reverse engineer how it is being used.

Comment: Gotcha, that's what I was afraid of but figured it didn't hurt to ask - thanks folks.